# What does it mean for a function to be a subset of natural numbers?

Tags: functions, logic

I am trying to prove the following, but I do not understand what it means for a function to be a subset of $N^{k+1}$. Can someone please explain it to me?

"Suppose $f:N^k\rightarrow N$ is a total function. Show that $f$ is a representation function iff $f$ is a representable subset of $N^{k+1}$."

Comment: A *function* with $n$ arguments in set theory is a $(n+1)$-ary relation, i.e. a subset of the $n+1$-time cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro example if you have $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$  you can represent it as  $$f= \{(x,y,z):z=x^2+y^2\}$$

The domain is two dimentional and the range is one dimentional so over all you have a three dimentional set.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of a function $\Bbb N^k\to\Bbb N$ is a subset of $\Bbb N^{k+1}$, and on the most basic level, a function *is* its graph.